# Update with SUM and LIMIT, rolling SUM

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have 2 tables, **`SVISE`** and **`OVERW`**

Inside **`OVERW`** I have some scores with person ids and the date of that score.
E.g

```
p_id    degrees    mo_date
5        10.2      2013-10-09
5        9.85      2013-03-10
8        14.75     2013-04-25
8        11.00     2013-02-22
5        5.45      2013-08-11
5        6.2       2013-06-10
```

**`SVISE.ofh`** field must be updated with the **sum of the last three records** 
(for a specific person, ordered by date descending), so for person with id 5, the sum would result from the rows

```
5        10.2      2013-10-09
5        5.45      2013-08-11
5        6.2       2013-06-10
```

*sum=21.85*.

**Desired final result** on **`SVISE`**, based on the values above:

```
HID OFH     START
5   21.85   October, 16 2013   ##(10.2 + 5.45 + 6.2)
5   21.5    September, 07 2013 ##(5.45 + 6.2 + 9.85)
5   0       March, 05 2013     ##(no rows)
8   25.75   October, 14 2013   ##(14.75 + 11)
3   0       October, 14 2013   ##(no rows)
5   0       March, 05 2012     ##(no rows)
```

*`OFH`was 0 initially*

I can get the total sum for a specific person, but I can't use limit to get the last 3 rows. It gets ignored.

This is the query I use to retrieve the **sum of all degrees per person** for a given date:

```
UPDATE SVISE SV
SET 
SV.ofh=(SELECT sum(degrees) FROM OVERW WHERE p_id =SV.hid 
AND date(mo_date)<date(SV.start) 
AND year(mo_date)=year(SV.start))
```

I cannot just use limit with sum:

```
UPDATE SVISE SV
SET 
SV.ofh=(SELECT sum(degrees) FROM OVERW WHERE p_id =SV.hid 
AND date(mo_date)<date(SV.start) 
AND year(mo_date)=year(SV.start)
ORDER BY mo_date DESC 
LIMIT 3)
```

This does not work.

I have tried with `multi-table updates` and with `nested queries` to achieve this.
Every scenario has known limitations that block me from accomplishing the desired result.

- Nested queries cant *see* the parent table. `Unknown column 'SV.hid'in 'where clause'`
- Multi-table update cant be use with limit. `Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT`

Any solution will do. There is no need to do it in a single query. If anyone wants to try even with an intermediate table.

An [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/018f06/1) is also available.

Thanks in advance for your help.

*--Update--*

Here is the solution from Akash: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cf1a/1

Comment: In your queries, you are verifying that the years match. Is that part of the requirement? Also, what column or columns constitute the primary key of `SVISE` (or `svice`, as per the SQL Fiddle)?

Comment: @AndriyM, I want the "last" 3 degrees from a person and the only filter is the date. Last 3 degrees from now or last 3 degrees from yesterday etc.

Comment: Does this data set correspond to that provided in the sqlfiddle? If not, consider providing the correct result set for that sqlfiddle data set, and update your question accordingly. It would sensible to provide the complete result set for the overw table ONLY.

Comment: Also, are you sure these should be FLOAT and not DECIMAL?

Comment: Hi Strawberry, yes its the same data set, I changed decimal to float only to make it easier for someone to understand it visually, and some random data. Fiddle structure is the same, you can change it, insert whatever rows you like or even make it contain the same rows as the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work,

**UPDATED** to have a join on `svice`

```
UPDATE
svice SV
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    hid,
    start,
    sum(degrees) as degrees
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT 
        *,
        IF(@prev_row <> unix_timestamp(start)+P_ID, @row_number:=0,NULL),
        @prev_row:=unix_timestamp(start)+P_ID,
        @row_number:=@row_number+1 as row_number
      FROM 
        (
        SELECT
          mo_date,
          p_id,
          hid,
          start,
          degrees
        FROM 
          OVERW 
          JOIN svice sv ON ( p_id = hid 
                            AND date(mo_date)<date(SV.start) 
                            AND year(mo_date)=year(SV.start) )
         ORDER BY
          hid,
          start,
          mo_date desc
        ) sub_query1
        JOIN ( select @row_number:=0, @prev_row:=0 ) sub_query2
      ) sub_query
    where
      row_number <= 3
    GROUP BY 
      hid,
      start
  ) sub_query ON ( sub_query.hid = sv.hid AND sub_query.start = sv.start )
SET 
  SV.ofh = sub_query.degrees
```

**Note:** Check this with your updated data, the test data provided could not yield the results you expected due to the date conditions

Comment: thank you, but I need to use a date filter. I need to use the "WHERE date(mo_date)<date(SV.start)" before the ORDER BY.

Comment: if every `svice` record has 1 corresponding entry for a `overw p_id` entry, you can directly do a join in the inner most query

Comment: is it that the `SVISE` table, would be having one entry per p_id ?

Comment: In every row, `SVICE` table has a date, based on that and on hid I need to find the sum of 3 degrees of `OVERW`, for every row of `SVICE`.

Comment: But is it that the `SVISE` table has only 1 single entry for every `overw p_id`?

Comment: No, its a rolling sum because in every `SVICE` record there is a distinct date

Comment: can you please provide some demo entries for the `SVISE` table.., what do you mean by a rolling sum?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39316/discussion-between-kabamaru-and-akash)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UPDATE svice SV
JOIN (SELECT SUM(degrees)sumdeg,p_id FROM(SELECT DISTINCT degrees,p_id FROM OVERW,svice WHERE OVERW.p_id IN (SELECT svice.hid FROM svice) 
AND date(mo_date)<date(svice.start) 
AND year(mo_date)=year(svice.start)ORDER BY mo_date DESC )deg  group by p_id)bbc 
      ON bbc.p_id=SV.hid 
      SET 
SV.ofh=bbc.sumdeg where p_id =SV.hid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95b42/42

Getting closer,now it "only" needs a limit in GROUP BY.

Comment: Mihai, I've set up a fiddle. I've pasted the fiddle link inside my question. You'll notice that the result value is wrong

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64d96/1 I cant get it to update all the rows,somebody more knowledgeable is needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Two assumptions:

1. You can figure out how to turn this into an update, and
2. A PK exists on (id,mo_date)

Then you can do this -

```
SELECT p_id
     , SUM(degrees) ttl
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
         FROM overw x 
         JOIN overw y 
           ON y.p_id = x.p_id 
          AND y.mo_date >= x.mo_date 
        GROUP 
           BY p_id
            , mo_date HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
     ) a 
 GROUP 
    BY p_id;
```

Comment: Give it a shot here: sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64d96/1

Comment: Strawberry, results should not be grouped, check the "desired result" in my question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm slow, but let's ignore svice for now. 
Can you show the correct result and the working for each row below...

```
+------+---------+------------+--------+
| p_id | degrees | mo_date    | result |
+------+---------+------------+--------+
|    5 |    6.20 | 2013-06-10 |      ? | 
|    5 |    5.45 | 2013-08-11 |      ? |
|    5 |   10.20 | 2013-10-09 |  21.85 | <- = 10.2+5.45+6.2 = 21.85 
|    8 |   14.75 | 2013-04-25 |      ? |
|    5 |    9.85 | 2013-03-10 |      ? |
|    8 |   11.00 | 2013-02-22 |      ? |  
+------+---------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Earlier, you were able to obtain an intermediate result of 10.2+5.45+6.2 = 21.85 for row 3 above, without reference to any other tables.

Comment: Here Strawberry, I've inserted your data so you can check it, with the solution from Akash

Comment: Seems SQLFiddle is down!